# Prove that every tree with at least two vertices contains a young parent.

Tags: graph-theory, induction

What would be an elegant way to prove that every tree with at least two vertices contains a young parent?

I was thinking of using induction, with a base case of n = 2 (n is the number of vertices) and an assumption : it's true for n = p

But then I struggle making the proof in a mathematical way. Yet, I can see how is it true using a graphic representation of a graph.

Comment: What do you mean by a *young parent*?

Comment: By young parent, I mean all vertices whose children are all leaves (so they don't have any children)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the result is false. Among all counterexamples let $T$ be a tree with the smallest possible number of vertices; clearly $T$ has more than $2$ vertices. Let $v$ be a leaf of $T$, and let $T'$ be the tree that remains after $v$ is removed from $T$. $T'$ has at least $2$ vertices and fewer vertices than $T$, so $T'$ has a young parent $u$, and it’s easy to verify that $u$ is a young parent in $T$ as well. This contradiction shows that there cannot be any counterexamples.

Comment: Ok, so you don't use any induction? This proof by contradiction is straightforward, I like it.

Comment: @Pierre: This actually is a proof by induction, but in a form that often isn’t taught. Any argument by induction can be converted into an argument that there is no smallest counterexample (for some suitable notion of *smallest*), and vice versa. If you look closely, you’ll see that the argument that I gave to show that $T$ really would have a young parent is essentially the induction step of a proof by induction on the number of vertices in the tree. But I find that for non-computational proofs by induction the *smallest counterexample* approach is often a little easier to state.

Comment: All right, thank you then!

Comment: @Pierre: You’re welcome!